# Button is not visible because of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have the following xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridIssue.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DataGridIssue"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Test button 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=TestList}"/>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Test button 2"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And C# ViewModel code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace DataGridIssue
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Test> TestList { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            TestList = new ObservableCollection<Test>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
            {
                var item = new Test();
                item.TestString = "Element " + i.ToString();
                TestList.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public string TestString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The thing is that the second button is not visible. As far as I understand the button is always below the end of the datagrid (what happens to be outside the window) and if the datagrid does not have the vertical scroll the button is visible. How can this be solved?

EDIT: I would like to avoid assigning height explicitly.

EDIT2: The following did the trick:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Test button 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=TestList}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Test button 2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Grid` with three rows:

```
...
 <Window.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Test button 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=TestList}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Test button 2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I would like to avoid using the height.

Comment: @DmitryTimofeev you can use `Auto` to autosize row height. Check my answer again:)